# Defined order just for one spec file

Tags: ruby, rspec2

I prefer to run my RSpec (2.14) specs in random order so I have added

```
config.order = 'random'
```

to my spec_helper

However, for one and only one file I need to run them in the order they are written.

I have modified my file as below

```
describe ApiAuthentication do 
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.order = 'defined'
  end

  it'....'
  end
end
```

But they are still executed in random order.

Is there a way to specify defined order just for 1 file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://mettadore.com/analysis/using-rspec-with-mixed-random-and-ordered-tests/) suggests it is.  Look at the [Configuration#order_groups_and_examples](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration%3aorder_groups_and_examples) method.

Comment: Both these links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done this in Rspec 2 - In my case I have a mix of ordered and unordered tests within the one spec file, so I used the following:

```
# order by a number at start of the description (default 0) and then random
# note 'describe' groups always sort after 'it' examples
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.order_groups_and_examples do |list|
    list.sort_by { |item| [item.description.sub(/^(\d*).*/, '\1').to_i, rand] }
  end
end
```

Combined with grouping using describe, this solved my requirements (most tests I didn't care about the order, but a few I wanted in order, or at the end). For example:

```
it "1: starts when asked to"
it "1: should do something"
it "waves happily"
it "snores loudly"
describe "9: at the end" do
  it "stops when asked to"
end

describe "4: some grouping" do
  it "does another thing"
  it "has weight"
end

describe "4: another group" do
  it "waddles like a duck"
  it "quacks like a duck"
end
```

is run in the following order:

```
# next two in random order
it "waves happily"
it "snores loudly"

# next two in random order
it "1: should do something"
it "1: starts when asked to"

# next two describe blocks in random order, and their examples within then in random order
describe "2: another group" do
  it "waddles like a duck"
  it "quacks like a duck"
end
describe "2: some grouping" do
  it "does another thing"
  it "has weight"
end

# NOTE: an it "9: something" example without a surrounding
#  describe block would run before all the describe blocks.

# this will run at the end
describe "9: at the end" do
  it "stops when asked to"
end
```